# cannot run sudo apt install wireless-tools on ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am completely new to ubuntu server and I am having issues configuring the network on my ubuntu 18.10 live server to be able to connect on the wifi only.
When I run the command `sudo apt install wireless-tools` I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libiw30 wireless-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libiw30 wireless-tools
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 125 KB of archives.
After this operation, 351 KB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to conntinue? [Y/n]y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 libiw30 amd64 30~pre912ubuntu1
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
.
.
.
.
E:Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing
```

I tried both and it is still not working.
I appreciate any suggestions about how to do that.

Comment: First you need to connect to the Internet, then you can download packages.

Comment: I did connect to internet via mobile usb tethering...the laptop I'm using doesn't have an ethernet port.

Answer (score 0):

> Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Your `sudo apt install...` command is doing exactly what it's supposed to do, the problem is that your computer is unable to resolve the domain name archive.ubuntu.com.

Comment: I think it was because I was using USB tethering while the interface wasn't properly configured.